# Laravel - Custom Plugin with Template

Tags: view, laravel, laravel-4

I have these "containers" which each holds one major section of my code. A page is therefore built up of a few containers, and they all look and behave the same. In my route directory, I have the following architecture

```
app
    /containers
        /Main
           MainContainer.php
           ContainerName1.php
           ContainerName2.php
           ...
        /Side
           SideContainer.php
           ContainerName3.php
           ContainerName4.php
           ...
        /Aux
           AuxContainer.php
           ContainerName5.php
           ContainerName6.php
           ...
        BaseContainer.php
```

So `MainContainer.php`, `SideContainer.php`, and `AuxContainer.php` all extend `BaseContainer.php`, and each `ContainerName#.php` extends the appropriate container. I currently have all the HTML/Views done within these containers themselves. But I wanted to move all HTML/Views to a template.

Should I have the templates in the `/views` folder, or should I keep it in this `/containers` folder? The reason why I may want to keep it in the `/containers` folder is because there will be a `base.blade.php`, and `main.blade.php` (and side/aux), and then one per ContainerName#. So it may stay cleaner if they are all there?? If I can do this, how do I call it?

Comment: what are you trying to build exactly ? what is BaseContainer ?

Comment: My containers hold my code. For instance, on this page, each post is a container. The replies go into the "footer" of the container, with each reply itself being a container.

Comment: So, you're talking about partials?

Comment: Well, I don't want to call the partials directly. I want to call a plugin, and the plugin returns a View and then that gets rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is partially a matter of opinion, but I'll toss my opinion in here and I suppose people can downvote me if they disagree.

I think it's better to keep all your views in `/views`, mostly because that's the appropriate and expected place for them.  If anyone other than you were to maintain this project, they'd look for views in `/views`, and I think they'd be throughly confused if they were stored in some containers.

Here's what my view structure looks like in my project:

```
views
    /layouts
        main.blade.php
    /includes
        analytics.blade.php
        navbar.blade.php
        flair.blade.php
        ...
    /account
        main.blade.php
        public-listing.blade.php
        public-profile.blade.php
        ...
    /game
        listing.blade.php
        settings.blade.php
        ...
    about.blade.php
    contact.blade.php
    help.blade.php
```

I have my main templates in `layouts` (which is essentially my stock bootstrap code), I have little bits that I'll include in `includes` (things that will never be webpages on their own, but make other web pages work), and the rest goes in a sub folder depending on the controller.  From each of my "full" views, the top line is `@extends('layouts.main')` and that makes sure it inherits the correct layout (if there was more than one, although there isn't in my example).

I think something like this could easily work for your project, and would go a long way in making it easier for you and anyone else to maintain.